# How to Create a SubReport in Dynamics AX 2012 R3

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

http://mcaconnect.com/blog/how-to-create-a-subreport-in-dynamics-ax-2012-r3/

I gone through this blog, now my issue is sub report is not displaying, getting error like:

> Error: SubReport Could not be Shown
>
> SubReport->Properties->Parameters (Which parameters we need to pass in Parameters)

Comment: Do you pass the values to the parameters in the subreport control properties?

Comment: yes i need to pass the the parameter, i did according to above link but i am getting error.please go through the above link. they are passing parameter